Liquibase validation error while modifying composite key in against SQL Server
I am trying to add new column to existing composite-key, but I am getting below error. Looking for help.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!! ERROR: DATABASE CHANGE VIOLATIONS FOUND !!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

1 violation(s) found:

alt_prtmst.wh_id: New column is a PK.

My changeset looks like this:
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 001-add_wh_id_to_alt_prtmst
      author: krishna
      changes:
        - dropPrimaryKey:
            constraintName: alt_prtmst_pk
            dropIndex: true
            schemaName: ${schemaName}
            tableName: alt_prtmst
        - addColumn:
            tableName: alt_prtmst
            schemaName: ${schemaName}
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: wh_id
                  type: nvarchar(32)
                  remarks: The warehouse to support single item scan (UPC scanning).
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  defaultValue: "----"
        - addPrimaryKey:
            schemaName: ${schemaName}
            tableName: alt_prtmst
            columnNames: alt_prtnum,prtnum,prt_client_id,alt_prt_typ,wh_id
            constraintName: alt_prtmst_pk

I tried dropping primary key, associated index and adding primary key after column is added.
